# How can I listen to the change in input and then change the text?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have this code in HTML:

```
<label for="date">START DATE:
    <input id="date" name="date" type="number"> <span>days</span>
<label>
```

Now I want to make that if a user inputs `1` as a value in the `input` the `span` should change into the `day`, and if it has more than `1` day it should remain `days`. How can I make this with `*ngIf`?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean change value span tag depending on whether it is 1 or other number?

Comment: Exactly what I mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

```
<input id="date" name="date" type="number" #myInput>
<span>day{{myInput.value <= 1 ? '' : 's'}}</span>
```

**original**

```
<input ngModel (ngModelChange)="doSomething($event)" id="date" name="date" type="number"> <span>days</span>
```

With this form you can bind to a field. If the field is a getter/setter, then you can also execute code when the value changes:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="someprop"" id="date" name="date" type="number"> <span>days</span>
```

You can also use

```
<input (change)="doSomething($event)" id="date" name="date" type="number"> <span>days</span>
```

or

```
<input (input)="doSomething($event)" id="date" name="date" type="number"> <span>days</span>
```

Comment: So it can't be done with *ngIf only? I should make a function for it?

Comment: I'll update my answer. I didn't fully understand your question at first.

Comment: This works great. But let's say I want it to keep 'day' if the value is 1 and if the field is empty. I've tried this, but it doesn't work: 

`<span>day{{myInput.value == (1 && ')? '' : 's'}}</span>`

Comment: Try `myInput.value <= 1  ? '' : 's'`

Comment: Mate this works amazing, you are a genious! :) For learning purposes, why my code didn't work? Thanks!

Comment: You can't compare one value with two others.  `myInput.value == (1 && '')` would compare `myInput.value` with `(1 && '')` which would be `''`) and therefore would only match an empty input. With your approach you would nee `myInput.value == 1 || myInput.value == '' || myInput.value == null ? ...`

Comment: Gunter, if it's not too much, may I extend my answer? Do You want to go to a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138938/discussion-between-gunter-zochbauer-and-eric-dummy).

Comment: I'm back, please check the chat.

Comment: I'm there, waiting for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with ngIf directive, but still that seems wrong approach.
In my opinion you can change value in code and just display it in span tag, but it seems you have certain task to do it with ifs

```
<input id="date" name="date" type="number" [(ngModel)]="selectedNumber">
<span *ngIf="selectedNumber==1">day</span>
<span *ngIf="selectedNumber!=1">day</span>
```